# Can be changed to batch file?

Tags: batch, mp4, png

I would like to create a `.bat` file that converts all `.png` files in a folder into individual `.mp4` files that have the same name as the `.png` file:

- This converts a `.png` into a 30s video, however how do I change this into a `.bat` file?

  ```powershell
  # Makes one specific file into a named file
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "img.png" -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "out.mp4"
  ```

**The goal is to have all .png files in a folder to make 30 second individual .mp4 files with using a .bat file**

Comment: A batch file is just a text file with commands input one per line and saved with a `.bat` extension to make it an executable script; however, I think what you're asking is how to use variables in a batch script so you don't need to manually add each file's name to the command(s) within the script?  If so, please add that to your question, as it's currently unclear precisely what you're needing help with.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to try the following Batch Script (I didn't completely test it) :

```
for %%A in (*.png) do (
    ffmpeg -loop 1 -i "%%~nA.png" -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p "%%~nA.mp4"
)
```

You have to put the script in the folder containing the png files.

This script iterate over all png file of the folder and run the command for each file.

Comment: thank you for your help! the script seems to work but it doesn't like my png files with spaces in the name, is there any way around that?

Comment: I've updated the code to correct this issue. You can try with the new version.

Comment: Thank you again, that worked perfect!